# How to redirect references to strong named .NET assemblies to weakly named local builds

Tags: .net, .net-assembly

I'm having a few problems with strong named library dependencies in .NET. My project itself is not strong named and I'm using nuget for all 3rd party libraries - these are a mixture of both strong and weakly named, generally OSS, projects.

As an example, assume the following dependency chain,

```
My Project ---> A ---> B
```

and say I've found an issue in OSS library `B`, and thus maintain a local fork with bugfixes and customisations. However `B` is strongly named and the private key is not available, so I can only generate weakly named local builds.

How can I build my project such that the binary version of `A` references my local copy of `B`? By default I get an assembly binding error at run-time, presumably as the public key token within my locally built assembly is `null` and does not match that expected by `A`. As far as I can tell, `binding-redirects` within `App.config` are for redirecting across assembly version numbers, and not public key values.

I did manage to resolve this by disassembling `A`, removing the `publickeytoken` field within the assembly reference to `B` in the IL and reassembling - this works but seems pretty hacky.

Is there are better way to achieve the intended outcome? It seems to be a major drawback and somewhat counterproductive when using OSS packages on .NET - as instead I have to wait for a new binary release and hope it includes the fixes I'm after.

Comment: Doesn't that defeat the purpose of strong naming?

Comment: Absolutely - that is my intention :) Although you could argue that strong naming somewhat defeats the purpose of OSS library development, and is presumably the reason ASP.NET vNext is moving away from it.

Comment: So then, your question is "how do I defeat this security feature"?  Even if you disagree with it, that's not the kind of topic that is appropriate for StackOverflow (IMHO).

Comment: Indirectly yes, but I fail to see how it's inappropriate - it's a technical question, to which I can not find a answer, and I'm not after nefarious purposes - I just wish to continue development using a local build. It arises due to a conflict between strong naming and OSS development, whereby developers have locally-modified branches. In such a case, how can I tell the CLR to override any conflicts and trust my locally-built library (if only temporarily for dev until a new signed binary is released upstream)? Furthermore, how else may one track the `git master` of a strong named library?